# Saving firebase bandwidth by shortening field names?

Tags: firebase

Using Firebase I'm giving the fields easily human-readable names, such as "timestamp", "last_changed", "message_direction" etc.

Are the field names part of the data exchange for every single "row"?

Meaning, would I save bandwidth by shortening the field names?

Comment: You could probably save some bandwidth, but I doubt it would be worth the loss in readability. If you want to see what Firebase sends/receives, set `Firebase.enableLogging(true);` early in your script. You can also get an indication of the data size using `Firebase.INTERNAL.stats(firebaseRef);`. (See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18922268/209103 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/25025571/209103)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As Frank pointed out: Yes, they do affect bandwidth. However, if you do the math, you'll see that bandwidth is rarely worth the effort and obfuscation, and that generally your data payload will vastly eclipse the few extra characters of the keys.

Let's consider an average chat message:

```
{
  "sender": "typicaluserid:12345678901234567890",
  "timestamp": 1410193850266,
  "message": "Hello world. All your base are belong to us!"
}
```

Okay, so first let's look at the payload for this message. This is 163 bytes, UTF-8 encoded. if I changed the keys to meaningless three character ids (e.g. sdr, ts, and msg), then it would be 149 bytes. With some liberal padding for transaction overhead, let's say about 40 bytes, it's about a 2% savings, in exchange for needing a rosetta stone to read my data.

Next, let's consider bandwidth usage. If we have a very active, very massive chat system (i.e. we're raking in serious $$), we might have 10k active users sending an average of 50 messages per day. That means we'd be sending `200 bytes * 500k = 100MB` of data per day, or around `3GB` of data per month.

That means that I could support a massive chat system comfortably on Firebase's free plan without exceeding bandwidth limits.

If we take those 11 bytes, off, we have `189 * 500k * 30 = 2.8GB`. So not a significant difference for the effort.

Comment: this question is old so this may be outdated, but your calculations do not include the HTTP requests needed to perform writes and reads. Again, I may be completely wrong here, but that would include an extra ~400-600 bytes per message. Is this the case?

Comment: Not over websockets, which is the default. But there is a small overhead per packet of course.

Comment: Well written. Upvoted. Is the data compressed? ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915854/is-the-traffic-from-to-firebase-server-compressed )

Comment: rosetta stone bit made me laugh out actually loudly :'D helped me out a lot man, thanks :) amazing answer. yea not worth the headache

Comment: @Kato  Does bandwidth consumed by accessing deeply nested boolean and one level boolean is considerable? Ex: I have a path like `users/chats/events/random_id_dfdfdddffdfdfsffsdfdffszfdf/isOnline/` and I am thinking of converting this to more  flat structure like `online/uid`  will this save lot of bandwidth?  and I access this path 100 times for user per day on an average

Comment: It's fairly straightforward math from there. Determine how many bytes the string is, and multiply: `bytes` x `number of requests per user` x `number of users` = answer

Comment: @Kato Thank you

Answer (score 1):

My few cents for the sake of "lateral thinking" and "stating the obvious" : sometimes the shortening can have benefits other than bandwidth. For example readability, easier to type, less likely to make a typo, etc.

I recommend spending some time on finding the most concise names that would still be understandable.

/ MrObvious out