# Firebase efficency with keys of double length

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I see that a standard random key in Firebase have a length of 21 characters, for a matter of convenience I want to store a node key that is a sum of two keys.

An example, I have this structure

```
"User":{
  "48674dhfgr4352dpolkut":{
    "following": {
      "djfhet562957438tufhds": true,
      "dshjwog967582sgdjgkj0": true
    }
  }
}

"followerActivity": {
   "48674dhfgr4352dpolkut%2Edjfhet562957438tufhds": true,
   "48674dhfgr4352dpolkut%2Edshjwog967582sgdjgkj0: true
}
```

In the activity the key is equals to `uid + %2E + followingId`. In this mode I have some simplification in the client side.

My doubt is if it can be due to loss of efficiency, and whether it is better to store a normal key

Comment: If you store two keys of the same length, the resulting key will be of twice the original length. There's really not much more that can be said about it without considering a very specific use-case.

Comment: yes my only doubt  is if read thousands of nodes with double key size could slow down performance. i want use this method for convenience but  I would not lose performance in read mode, for example when i want to search a key in hundred of keys.

Comment: It's a simple matter of byte counts sent over the internet. So it depends on the number of bytes sent and the connection speed and not much else. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720109/saving-firebase-bandwidth-by-shortening-field-names/25729326#25729326