# Is the traffic from/to firebase database server compressed?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Perhaps a bit of a silly question, but, is the traffic from/to firebase DB server **compressed**?

If so, what algorithm(s)?

What compression ratios are usually occurring, for plain-text data being sent/received by firebase client?

Does the compression have a noticeable impact on CPU usage on today's devices?

Does the client code have some control over this aspect?

Are there differences in that regard, between the Java/Android/Web/iOS SDK-s?

EDIT: also, on which communication/transport layer(s) does the compression occur?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The communication between a Firebase client and its Database Servers goes over a secured web socket connection. The data is not compressed.

You can easily see this yourself by accessing the Firebase Database from your browser and then looking at the network tab. It'll show you exactly what data is being exchanged and in which format.